# Can't install geoplot package

Tags: python, pip, conda, geospatial, geoplot

I'm trying to install **geoplot** package for a few hours now but I can't understand why I can't do it. I saw several links in here just saying "only use conda and it will work" but neither `conda install -c conda-forge geoplot` or `pip install geoplot` are working.

The best question I saw in this matter was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177062/cartopy-not-able-to-identify-geos-for-proj-install-on-windows) but even following the solution step by step isn't doing the job.

I'm on a Windows 10 64bit, with:

- Python (3.7.6)
- conda (4.8.2)
- pip (20.0.2)
- geos (0.2.3)
- proj (0.2.0)
- and shapely (1.8.0) already installed.

Also, I'm with geopandas (0.10.2) fully functional and with GDAL_DATA path already on my Windows' environment variables.

Here is the error while tryinh to install via `pip`:

```
Collecting rasterio
  Using cached rasterio-1.2.10.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\pepereira\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\pepereira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\PEPERE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpisdpcfsw'
       cwd: C:\Users\PEPERE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f8mf8fv_\rasterio
  Complete output (2 lines):
  INFO:root:Building on Windows requires extra options to setup.py to locate needed GDAL files. More information is available in the README.
  ERROR: A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\pepereira\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\pepereira\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\PEPERE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpisdpcfsw' Check the logs for full command output.
```

via `conda` command line it really takes a long long time and shows a bunch of dependencies conflict... Does anybody knows how can I solve this issue? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have to restrict to that Python version? Why isn't Conda updated? Do you have to install in the **base** environment? Would be substantially easier if not.

Comment: Hey, merv, thank you for your reply! Unfortunetely I'm on my companies' laptop so indeed I have some restrictions on updating everything. No need to be specifically in base environment, but as I already have geopandas on it, thought that would be easier to do in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wan't able to solve this problem on my base environment, so in order to install `geoplot` I had to create a new environment on conda. Will post what I've done here below in case of anyone in the future come across this same problem:

```
conda create -n geoEnv python=3.8
```

After that I've installed directly geoplot through conda insted of (GDAL, fiona, proj, etc.) > geopandas > geoplot, because doing that I was having the same dependencie problems, even on a brand new environment, so:

```
conda activate geoEnv    
conda install -c conda-forge geoplot
```

From here I just installed jupyter using `pip` because I don't know why trying it with conda was also pointing out dependencie problems as well...

I don't know if it was my packages or python versions but with this solution above I was able to successfully instal `geoplot`.

Bonus tip: installing `ipykernel` and `nb_conda_kernels` packages on your new environment/base could help you out to manage different envs